# Jquery form submit event don't work if i trigger manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i have this simple script where i try to stop form submision for make some ajax call and after i want to submit form manually, but this doesn't work, I try over 20 solutions. I try event to stop form submit with prevent default and fire latter in callback as i see in some example but for me give recursion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#my-form-submit').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#my-form').submit(function() {
                    alert('test');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form method="post" id="my-form" action='#'>
        <input type="submit" name="my-submit" value="Submit this form!" id="my-form-submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: You are not submitting the form, you are binding a submit event listener, just like how you bound a click event to the button. `$('#my-form').submit()` would submit it.

Comment: Can you please also add the ajax calls that you want to execute before submitting the form? And as @epascarello mentioned form submition would be just `$('#my-form').submit()`

Comment: Submit function without callback dont refresh and post page in a normal way. Doesn t matter what ajax call i make because ajax it s ok. But after the normal post with refreshing page to send result directly to php doesn t happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attached a event listener for when the form will submited.

To submit the form, just pass the method submit() without any parameter, or like so:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function() {
      alert('test');
}).submit();
```

Comment: I will try this. But this will pake page refresh as i havent any javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to capture event before send a form, you only need to use .submit()

```
      $(function() {
           $('#my-form').submit(function() {
                alert('Check it is showed before submit test');
            });

    });
```

Comment: Of i do that the ajax call don t happend because o think the form is submitting fast and make page refresh

Comment: Try it then.  $(document).ready(function() {
       
            $("form").submit(function(e){
                alert('submit intercepted');
                e.preventDefault(e);
            });
        });